# Deploying app skips resource files

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm banging my head off the wall on this one...I have a (so far fairly simple) google app engine project. During runtime I want to read in some XML files (resource file, not servable-static file) for processing. Having done a bit of research, I settled on reading the resource file through the servlet context (similar to the following). Works just fine on the dev server.

final InputStream inputStream1 = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/" + pathToXmlFile);

Problem: Doesn't work in the cloud. First I thought the way how I am loading the resource is wrong, but I have noticed that the XML file in question doesn't appear to be uploaded at all. It is currently located here:

> src/main/webapp/data/stuff.xml and
>   src/main/webapp/WEB-APP/data/stuff.xml

(I wasn't sure where to place the XML file, so I duplicated it into two locations.) The deploy log shows how the files are skipped:

2017-08-10 13:13:42,451 DEBUG    root            Skipping upload of [data/stuff.xml]

2017-08-10 13:13:42,461 DEBUG    root            Skipping upload of [WEB-INF/data/stuff.xml]

I have tried a number of things, without success, to get the file deployed. Things I tried:

- Clear out the temp staging directory
- Manually clean the build
- Renamed directory / files
- Include the file within the classes directory
- Playing around with the resource-files section in the appengine-web.xml file (removing it, using various syntaxes)
- Removing older versions of the app from the cloud
- Restart Eclipse

FYI, current content of appengine-web.xml

```
<resource-files>
  <include path="/data/*.xml" />
  <include path="data/*.xml" />
</resource-files>
```

(Not sure if the slash is required....)

Note that the deploy does work for changed/new .class files, so my changes to Java classes are uploaded just fine. Somehow the deploy mechanism doesn't recognize that the XML file must also be uploaded.

FYI - Windows, Eclipse 4.7, Java 8, Cloud Tools 1.2.0.201706082053

Any help appreciated, especially if anybody knows how the deploy mechanism decides which files to deploy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<resource-files>
  <include path="/data/**.xml" />
</resource-files>
```

This should include all xml files in `data/` and its subdirectories.

Their [documentation on include and exclude syntax](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#include_exclude), as I'm sure you're aware, is pretty skimpy. I'm pretty sure you want the double asterisk there though, and a bit more sure that you want the leading slash. I'm trying to find more info on it now, and will post a link if I do.

Comment: At the end of the section you referenced: `Note: If the path string doesn't start with a slash, then the HTTP headers, if any, work on App Engine but do not work on the Development Server.`

Comment: Now using /data/**.xml as suggested. Originally it didn't make a difference, but then I "touched" the XML file (added some white space in it), and it seems to be uploaded now. The log says "Uploading ... staging\__static__/data/stuff.xml" - the "static" worries me a bit, but I will give it a try and see if it works in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Brendan, the ** did the trick. FYI, the setup is now as follows:

```
<resource-files>
  <include path="/data/**.xml" />
</resource-files>

<static-files>
  <exclude path="/data/**.xml" />
</static-files>
```

Just using a single * was not good enough for "any XML file", it had to be **. As side-effect of the resource-files entry, the XML file now suddenly was also available as static file, accessible through the browser. So the exclude section inside static-files prevents the exposure of this. Not sure if this is overly elegant or the easiest/cleanest way to do it, but it works...

FYI, the "data" directory is contained directly underneath "webapp", and to access the resource the code is: servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/data/stuff.xml");

Note I also had to manually "touch" the XML file in order to get it to upload.

Thanks again.

Comment: FWIW, it is customary on StackOverflow (and all StackExchange sites) to just upvote the posts that helped you (thank you notes are actually considered unnecessary noise) and, if the post is an answer to your question you should also mark it as accepted (the check mark under the voting arrows/score).

Comment: @Mark Hollmann You can always comment on my answer or edit your question itself to include a follow-up or solution at the end that states my answer solved it, in addition to the extra info you want to add. And of course, please mark my answer as accepted if it worked for you :)

Comment: Sorry guys, still learning the ropes here. Your help is much appreciated!